# converting tiff to gif in php

Tags: php, python, image-manipulation, tiff

I need to convert tiff file to gif  . can some one give me php or python script to do that ?

Comment: It's not possible in PHP alone. Can you use ImageMagick?

Comment: I am not aware of ImageMagick. Should i download it... ?

Comment: you should provide more information about the context you are in. If this is for your own personal use, there are batch conversion tools, no need for a PHP or Python based solution

Answer (score 1):

Try [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) in conjunction with the [Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imagick.php) extension in PHP.

Comment: Can you provide some more information... how to use this ImageMagick ?

Comment: Just use phpThumb, but in order for it to work with TIFF's  you need to have the Imagick extension in your PHP instalation. You can find all the info you need on the links I provided.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

```
try
{
        $image = '/tmp/image.tiff';    
        $im = new Imagick();    
        $im->pingImage( $image );    
        $im->readImage( $image );    
        $im->setImageFormat( 'gif' );    
        $im->writeImage( '/tmp/image.gif' );
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```